# Remove Carriage Return From SQL PLUS Output

Tags: linux, windows, oracle, sqlplus

Recently I've began working on a project where we have a new vendor to consume a file that we're sending them. The file itself contains an extract from a few database tables, nothing major. It's generated from a Windows server using SqlPlus and connects to an Oracle DB to grab the data and spit it out to a file. So anyway, the vendor is processing the file on a linux system and since the file is coming from Windows I am finding it has a CRLF at the end of each line. They are stating they only want the LF at the end of the line and not the carriage return.

Is there a way to accomplish this using SqlPlus and do the output easily or am I stuck writing some small clean up batch to comb through the file and repalce CFLF with just LF? So far I've tried a few different options with CHR(10) but none are working quite right.

If anyone could provide any guidance I would greatly appreciate it!!!

Below are my before spool file settings:

```
set trimspool on
set wrap off
set feedback off
set termout off
CLEAR COLUMNS 
set heading off
set linesize 309
set pagesize 0
set arraysize 4
set space 0
```

Comment: I don't know how you can avoid Windows adding `chr(13)` (CR) in a text file after all the database processing is done; but as a general matter, I would imagine such things are much better taken care of on the receiving end. Do you have a Linux system on which you could do the clean-up for them? That would make much more sense than trying to do anything in Windows.

Comment: This makes sense to me as well. On the linux side that should be easy as pie to do that file manipulation.

Comment: The only possible way I can see doing it from my side is creating another step to edit the file after its spooled out, we'll see what happens.